# Remove the whitespace below the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my website http://randomawesomeness.tk/ and i want to get rid of the whitespace below the footer .and i dont want the scrolling thing to show up.

Comment: Please add code relevant to your problem directly to your question, I don't think we want to go to your site to see your code

Comment: As Marko said, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Unless you are on an exceedingly low resolution display a scrollbar is unlikely to appear on the page linked. In such cases a scrollbar is essential unless you develop media queries to detect such displays and modify the contents accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS for your footer.

`position: fixed;`
Position your footer relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

`bottom: 0;`
Keep the footer at bottom of viewport

`width: 100%;`
Make the footer large as the viewport.

---

```
footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        background: #29EE55;
        color: white;
        margin: -20px -23px 0px -20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
body {
    font-family: "Lobster",cursive;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :-

```
   body{
      margin:0;
    }
```

And on you footer following;

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100;
    margin:0;

}
```